# How to make the data_flow control of a matrix multiplier synthesizable?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I have designed a matrix-vector multiplier with systolic array architecture. I finally got the simulation to work. Now that I want to synthesize the design it seems that the data_flow control block is not synthesizable (the always block). And I think it because of using for loops with variable number of iterations. Could you please give me some tips to make it synthesizable?

My design has 64 (8 by 8 fixed) processing elements (PE) to do the multiply and accumulation (MAC) for the matrix multiplication, and I used a subset/all of them depending on inputs dimensions (up to 64 * 64). It gets the dimensions of the inputs (the matrix and the vector) from external CPU.
For example, if (M*N) matrix has M=5 and N=5 and (N *1) vector the result will be (M *1) vector and we will be using M_val number of PEs, that is 5. I used activation signal to activate M_val number of PEs.

**EDIT:** With the following code I get the message below from design compiler:

Warning:  /local/home/synth/systolic.sv:46: Out of bounds bit select W_reg[64], valid bounds are [0:63]. (ELAB-312)
Error:  /local/home/synth/systolic.sv:45: Loop exceeded maximum iteration limit. (ELAB-900)
*** Presto compilation terminated with 1 errors. ***

When I change the **M_val** upperbounds of the for loops to **M** and change the **m=cycle-N_val+1** to **m = 1**, it will synthesize but it doesn't simulate correctly (does not produce the right result for the multiplication).

Here is my code:

```
module systolic #(parameter DW = 8,

         // fixed! not meant to be change from outside
             parameter M = 8,
             parameter N = 8)
             (
                input clk,
                input reset,
                input reg[15:0] M_val,     // number of rows 
                input reg [15:0] N_val,    // number of columns
                input start_mult,

                input  [DW-1:0] W_i [0:M*N-1],
                input  [DW-1:0] X_i [0:N-1],
                
                output [2*DW:0] Y_o [0:M-1],
                output reg mult_done 
             );
              


reg [7:0] cycle;    // counts the cycles of multiplication process

reg  [DW-1:0] W_reg[0:M-1]; // regfile to hold W matrix elements
reg  [DW-1:0] X_reg;        // register to hold X vector elements at each cycle
integer m;

// ROW-MAJOR w_i
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (!reset) begin
    cycle <= 8'd0;
    mult_done <= 1'b0;
    X_reg <= 8'd0;
    for(m = 0; m < M; m = m + 1) begin
      W_reg[m] <= 8'd0;
    end
  end
  else if (start_mult) begin
    if (cycle == (M_val + N_val)) begin   // the number of cycles needed for the multiplication
      mult_done <= 1'b1;
      cycle <= 8'd0;
      for(m = 0; m < M_val; m = m + 1) begin // if change to M_val -> M
        W_reg[m] <= 8'd0;
      end
    end else if (cycle < N_val) begin        // N_val is the number of times we have to shift X values
      X_reg <= X_i[cycle];
      for(m = 0; m < M_val; m = m + 1) begin // if change to M_val -> M
        W_reg[m] <= W_i[(cycle-m) + m*N_val];

      end
    end else begin // if (cycle >= N) X will get zeros, its elements has been shifted to the last PE 
      X_reg <= 8'd0;
      
      // after N cycles the first PE is done processing, so the m index starts from 1, 
      // or we are feeding W elements to the PEs other than the first one.
      
       for (m=cycle-N_val+1; m < M_val; m = m + 1) begin //if change M_val -> M && m=cycle-N_val+1 it it will synthesize
        W_reg[m] <= W_i[(cycle-m) + m*N_val];
      end
    end
    cycle <= cycle + 8'd1;
  end
end
  

wire  [DW-1:0] Ws[1:0][0:M-1];
wire  [DW-1:0] Xs [0:M];


wire [2*DW:0] Ys [0:M-1];

reg [M-1:0] activate_reg;
wire activate_pe [M-1:0];

// at first all the PEs are activated.
always@(posedge reset or posedge start_mult) begin
    if(!reset)
      activate_reg = 64'hFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF;
    else if (M_val != 64)
      activate_reg  = (activate_reg >> M - M_val);
    else 
      activate_reg = 64'hFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF;
end




genvar i,j;

generate
  
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i + 1) begin: PE_activators
    assign activate_pe[i] = activate_reg[i];
  end 
  
  for (i = 0; i < M; i = i + 1) begin: Weights
    assign Ws[0][i] = W_reg[i];
  end 

  assign Xs[0] = X_reg;

  
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin: ROWs
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j = j + 1) begin: COLs
     PE #(DW)
         pe (
            .clk(clk),
            .reset(reset),
            .activate(activate_pe[i*8+j]),
            .w_i(Ws[0][i*8+j]),
            .x_i(Xs[i*8+j]),
            .w_o(),            // This can be float
            .x_o(Xs[i*8+j+1]),
            .mac(Ys[i*8+j])
         );
    end
  end
  
endgenerate

assign Y_o = Ys;

endmodule

module PE #(parameter DW = 8)
       (
        input clk,
        input reset,
        input activate,
        
        input  [DW-1:0]w_i,
        input  [DW-1:0]x_i,
        
        output reg  [DW-1:0] w_o,
        output reg  [DW-1:0] x_o,

        output reg [2*DW:0] mac
       );

wire  [2*DW:0] multiply = w_i * x_i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(!reset) begin
    w_o <= {DW{1'b0}};
    x_o <= {DW{1'b0}};
    mac <= {(2*DW +1){1'b0}};
  end
  else begin
    if(activate == 1) begin
      w_o <= w_i;
      x_o <= x_i;
      mac <= mac + multiply;

    end
  end

end

endmodule
```

So for (4*4) Matrix **W** and (4**1) vector **X**,

W = {w44,w43,w42,w41,  w34,w33,w32,w31,  w24,w23,w22,  w14,w13,w12,w11};

X = {x4, x3, x2, x1};

the dataflow/Timing for 4 PEs would be like this (please let me know if you need more info):

[image]

Comment: *it seems that the data_flow control block is not synthesizable* -- what does it mean? Did you get synthesis tool errors? warning? what do they say?

Comment: As you stated, the tools don't want a variable number of loop iterations.  The code loops over W_reg a maximum of M times.  In the case where you want to loop less than M times, what do you want to happen with the other values that are not getting assigned in the loop?  For example do you want them to stay the same?

Comment: @Mikef Thanks for your time. The other values can be zero or float. Basically, I want hardware generated for 'M' iterations. But using 'M_val' number of them, and If M_val is equal to M then using all of them, or assign values to all of them

Answer (score 1):

Change your loops to be a constant number of iterations and use an `if` statement to control what happens. E.g. change this:

```
        for (m=cycle-N_val+1; m < M_val; m = m + 1)
            W_reg[m] <= W_i[(cycle-m) + m*N_val];
```

to this:

```
        for (m = 0; m < M; m = m + 1)
            if ((m >= cycle-N_val+1) && (m < M_val))
                W_reg[m] <= W_i[(cycle-m) + m*N_val];
```

Or if you don't need the W_reg values to remain unchanged then just take the `if` out completely.

Also note that while this code looks simple, it's creating lots of multiplexers, multipliers and other things that need to complete in a single clock cycle. You might need to break this down into a longer pipeline to get good performance out of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give some suggestion on how to make the pipeline longer? design an FSM?

Comment: The general idea would be to do the multiply and subtract, save the results in a registers, then do the add, save that in a register, then do the mux, etc. For things like the multiply, you may want to use primitive blocks that do that, or write your code in a way that they can be inferred.